# COB in RVIZ without meshes

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, robot-description

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm working with COB (Care-O-Bot) simulations. Unfortunately my computer doesn't have enough RAM so I'm running Gazebo headless (without this feature simulation eats all my memory). But when I run RVIZ there is incomplete robot model - without meshes as you can see in first picture.

```
export ROBOT=cob3-2
export ROBOT_ENV=ipa-kitchen
export SIMX=-r
roslaunch cob_bringup sim.launch
```

[image: image description]

My question - is it caused by running Gazebo headless or is there different problem?

I tried to put just URDF model into Gazebo empty world and meshes are in their place... Used commands:

```
rosrun xacro xacro.py cob3-2.urdf.xacro > cob.urdf
roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file cob.urdf -urdf -model cob3-2
```

[image: image description]

I'm going to buy more memory of course but now I'm curious about this problem so any information will be appreciated.

UPDATE: [Ogre.log](http://mysharegadget.com/646576520), [output of system_info.sh](http://mysharegadget.com/331585359)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11511/cob-in-rviz-without-meshes/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 704 on 2011-10-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2011-10-19**:
Thanks for useful hint. I'll google for it. Link to ogre.log was added, but there is nothing strange...

**Comment by [LiMuBei](https://answers.ros.org/users/68/limubei/) on 2011-10-19**:
As far as I know there are some issues with Ogre3D (which rviz is built on) and Intel graphics cards. I'm not sure where, but somewhere there should be an ogre.log file from rviz. Maybe that can tell you more.

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2011-10-12**:
I'm using Intel integrated card. Maybe it could be reason... I tried to run erratic demo - robot also looks ok in Gazebo and not very well in RVIZ.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-10-12**:
what kind of graphics card does your laptop have?

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2011-10-12**:
Some code has been added so it should be now more clear what I'm doing.

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2011-10-12**:
I see... Ups. I think that it doesn't makes sense to run RVIZ in case if there is just model spawned in Gazebo. So I will remove third image again :-)

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-10-12**:
This makes me feel like it's not a headless Gazebo problem. In the third image, you have an error on your Robot Model in Rviz. What is that error?

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2011-10-12**:
No. I add third image showing how robot looks when running Gazebo with GUI and spawned urdf model.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-10-12**:
If you run Gazebo with it's GUI, does it fix the problem in Rviz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Hardware - so the problem is caused by Intel graphics which is not (well) supported by Ogre 3D.

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) with karma: 704 on 2011-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0